# SQL - SELECT DISTINCT user, when they match COLUMN1 VALUEA but do NOT have COLUMN1 VALUEB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table;

```
  user  | column2    |
--------+------------+
 tom    |   Created  |
 test   |   Created  |
 fred   |   Removed  |
 tom    |   Removed  |
 fred   |   Created  |
 holly  |   Created  |
 test   |   Modified |
```

I am looking to query the table to return users who have CREATED and no users who also have a REMOVED value. Also, users with MODIFIED can appear but not the row with their MODIFIED value.

Result should be:

```
 user  | column2    |
-------+------------+
 test   |   Created |
 Holly  |   Created |
```

I have only been using WHERE clauses, is there another way to achieve this?

Really appreciate any advice given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT user, column2
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE column2 = 'Created' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2 
                  WHERE t1.user = t2.user AND t2.column2 = 'Removed')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t.user,t.column2
FROM YourTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.user = s.user and s.column2 = 'Removed')
WHERE s.user is null
     and t.column2 ='Created'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, do a `GROUP BY`. Let the `HAVING` clause check that the user's min value is Created.

```
select user, min(column2)
from tablename
group by user
having min(column2) = 'Created'
   and max(column2) < 'Removed'
```